# Cross-domain ajax post with JSON data going to Rails controller as HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery

I'm making a cross-domain POST request and have set up headers in Rails 3.2 to accept the request appropriately - both the OPTIONS and POST request are received by the controller correctly.

The problem I'm finding is that Rails controller is receiving the JSON data as HTML. Why is this? How can I force the controller to treat it as JSON? (doing this from the client-side would be preferable)

If this is unclear let me know which messages/code I ought to post for better assistance. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding the `JSON` extension to the URL that you're making a request to, i.e. `https://your_domain.com/your_url.json`, which should force the `JSON` format.

Comment: seems like the most sensible/effective fix. I'm still confused why the cross-domain request is treated as html but the same request made non-cross-domain is treated as json - do you have any idea why?